# Как пользоваться mem::swap()?

Tags: массивы, функции, rust

Подскажите, можно ли воспользоваться функцией `mem::swap()`, чтобы поменять значения двух элементов одного массива?
Пытаюсь сделать нечто подобное:

```
let mut array = [1,2,3];
mem::swap(&mut array[0], &mut array[2]);
```

в результате получаю ошибку:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `array[..]` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:51:35
   |
51 |     mem::swap(&mut array[0], &mut array[2]);
   |                    --------       ^^^^^^^^- first borrow ends here
   |                    |              |
   |                    |              second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                    first mutable borrow occurs here
```

смысл ошибки ясен, но не пойму а как тогда сделать обмен значений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, ты хочешь частную реализацию swap для срезов - https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap

```
let mut v = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
v.swap(1, 3);
assert!(v == ["a", "d", "c", "b"]);
```

Просто `mem::swap` тут использовать не выйдет, потому что компилятор не даст получить две изменяемые ссылки на куски массива.